# Make Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2 HTML template compatible with Bootstrap 3 with minimal efforts

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have HTML template based on twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2. Is there is Way to make template compatible with version 3 with minimal efforts:) or i work on html elements from scratch:(

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is simply to replace your calls to the Bootstrap 2 CSS and JS files with the appropriate Bootstrap 3 CSS and JS files, and update the classes for the grid system, for example change span4 to col-md-4

Good luck!

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your template, you might find other elements that need to be changed. If it was me I would start with the page scaffolding ( conainter, row, and column classes) get that working and see how it looks. A lot of class names changed between BS 2.3 and 3, so you might find other things that need attention as well, like components, typography or may be in the navbar. Just make sure you have a backup copy of your original template and you can't go too far wrong ;)

Comment: @gill There are also some online tools for upgrading BS HTML which you might find useful, eg http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com .

Comment: Thnks buddy u make my day:)

Answer (score -1):

Try Bootstrap's Bootply updater (http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/). It's not 100% but does save a great deal of work.